DotNetZip is deprecated. What is the easiest replacement for .NET Framework 4.8?
We have a Solution targeting .NET Framework 4.8 with over 80 projects in it, and a few projects in this Solution reference a nuget package for DotNetZip. This has now been deprecated:

I would really like to avoid having to rewrite large chunks of code to target a different package. We started off using Ionic.zip. This package was deprecated a good while ago now, but it came with a recommendation "This package is deprecated. Use DotNetZip instead." and we replaced Ionic.Zip with DotNetZip. That was easy. But with the deprecation of DotNetZip all we're getting is "This package version is deprecated", without any recommendation re. what to replace it with.
Now what?

Software suggestion is off-topic. For deprecated code, you usually find a suggestion on the homepage of the product which in this case is https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd which suggests to migrate to System.IO.Compression. If you're very determined to not touch any code using this, then you might be able to write a wrapper around System.IO.Compression that's API-compatible to DotNetZip (I know neither pieces of software, so I can't tell you how easy that would be)

Yeah, I know. As I mentioned, when we first created the Solution we used Ionic.Zip, and when that was deprecated the deprecation message itself told us what to migrate to. This time no such information is given. I did find System.IO.Compression but it would constitute a complete rewrite. Funnily enough your suggestion to write a API-compatible wrapper did occur to me. I might just do that, if all else fails. Thanks for sharing the github link; I will go check it out.

@JoachimSauer
Please post your link to the github repository as an Answer and I will flag it as the accepted answer. That is exactly what I need. Thanks a million for that.

System.IO.Compression does not support passwords and is not a replacemnet for DotNetZip

Yes I think the "better" solution would be to fetch the DotNetZip.Semverd solution as suggested by @JoachimSauer .... Having said that, when I did fetch it there were a lot of compatibility problems so I eventually decided to just keep using the deprecated nuget package. It's far from ideal but at this point in time I don't think it's worthwhile spending a LOT of time on removing this dependency. I just wish the makers of DotNetZip hadn't simply abandoned the project without any way to move forward, unlike when Ionic.Zip was deprecated. The move to DotNetZip was trivial then.

@JoachimSauer I would like to close this question as answered because between the two of you I was able to come up with a solution that was as painless as possible. As it turns out, we use another 3rd party product, I'm afraid a quite expensive one, that includes a component that can handle Zip files, so I wrote a wrapper, as Joachim suggested. While it's not perfectly "compatible" I was able to get close enough to the original DotNetZip functionality to keep the cut and paste job relatively simple.

@Anders as per my comment to Joachim.

System.IO.Compression is somewhat incomplete, System.IO.Compression.ZipFile expands functionality, although still doesn't support encryption.

As per the discussion with Joachim Sauer and Anders I note that posting an actual recommendation for any named package would be off topic, so I will limit myself to a generic explanation of how I resolved the problem.
Joachim posted a link to https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd which contains the archived code base for DotNetZip. Maybe it could help someone to bring down this code and modify it to suit their own needs. For us it was overkill.
Joachim also suggested writing a wrapper around the native compression software system.io.compression and this may be a useful exercise for some people but Anders pointed out that this would not work if you need to replace DotNetZip with a fully compatible wrapper as system.io.compression does not support passwords, for example.
In the end I investigated our code base and found we use only a very limited subset of zipping functionality from DotNetZip. I also discovered that we use a paid for (and rather expensive) commercial 3rd party toolset that includes a component for handling archives.
So I did write a wrapper around this component that would allow me to replace the original Ionic.Zip calls we employed in various places in our software with calls to our own component that looked similar enough to make the cut&paste job of replacing the code straightforward.
Took me about a day to make sure it was done everywhere in the code where we used to use DotNetZip, and now our code no longer has this dependency.
My apologies if this is not enough information for anyone else who wishes to remove dependencies to DotNetZip

Posting a recommendation for any named package is not off topic; that's what the question expressly asked for; it just might be a violation of the rules. ;)

Fair enough :) ...

The big issue now is that there is a 9.8 scored vulnerability in DotNetZip (in the latest 1.16.0) and DotNetZip.Semverd itself is not longer maintained and thus archived by the dev.
As someone stated in the comments System.IO.Compression does not support encryption. And the only other "big" OSS library SharpZipLib seems to be unmaintained as well. So I think we have a serious problem now...
Does anyone know suitable alternatives? 7zip could be a candidate but using command line tool is not really convenient.

Okay, obviously there is SharpCompress which does even have more downloads than DotNetZip. Anyone any expereince with it?

While we keep the product we use current through nuget, it's licensed software and the licences are NOT cheap. Not sure it would even be very useful if I mentioned its actual name here?

Just found a new fork, ProDotNetZip, but only for .NET Standard 2.0
